# Apple Accelerate Framework vDSP_zvmags PACKED format?

Tags: iphone, signal-processing, fft

I saw some sample code that calls vDSP_zvmags using the complex results of a call to vDSP_fft_zrip in order to get the magnitude^2. The output of zrip says it's PACKED split complex format, but in the documentation for vDSP_zvmags it just says split complex.

Is the input to vDSP_zvmags also the PACKED format, or does some manipulation need to be done before passing?

Many Thanks
Ray

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to unpack the result of vDSP_fft_zrip(). None of the other functions expect data packed that way. [Some info on the actual unpacking here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8845542/understanding-fft-in-auriotouch2/8854198#8854198)

Answer (score 0):

Executing fft using vDSP_fft_zrip on N point data gives you N/2 point PACKED split complex where in index 0, the real part shows the DC amount (index 0 of fft) and the imaginary part shows Nyquist amount (index N of fft).
for more details: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Performance/Conceptual/vDSP_Programming_Guide/UsingFourierTransforms/UsingFourierTransforms.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40005147-CH3-SW1

One trick you can use vDSP_zvmags and get the correct result is like this:

```
const int LOG2_N = 10 ; // (say N=1024)
const int N = 1 << LOG2_N ;

FFTSetup fftSetup;
DSPSplitComplex tempSplitComplex;

x = new float[N] ;    // N point data you can put your data 
X = new float[N/2+1] ; // magnitude of fft of signal from index 0 (dc) to N/2 (Nyquist)

tempSplitComplex.realp = new float[N/2];
tempSplitComplex.imagp = new float[N/2];

fftSetup = vDSP_create_fftsetup(LOG_N, kFFTRadix2);
vDSP_ctoz((DSPComplex *) x, 2, &tempSplitComplex, 1, N/2 ) ;
// perform fft
vDSP_fft_zrip(fftSetup, &tempSplitComplex, 1, LOG_N, kFFTDirection_Forward) ;
// calculating square of magnitude for each value
vDSP_zvmags(&tempSplitComplex, 1, X, 1, N/2); 
// after this line X[0] is incorrect and X[N] is not calculated,
// but others are correct, so we need to fix those two (X[0], and X[N])
// DC and Nyquist ffts' imaginary parts are zero, 
// so Nyquist fft is stored in imaginary part of DC fft
X[0] = tempSplitComplex.realp[0] * tempSplitComplex.realp[0];  // DC squared
X[N/2] = tempSplitComplex.imagp[0] * tempSplitComplex.imagp[0]; // Nyquist squared
```