# iPhone app audio recording only in above certain frequency

Tags: iphone, ios, audio, voice, frequency

I am currently engaged in a audio recording based application for iPhone and iPad. Here I have done the basic audio recording feature myself, but I don't have any idea about how to record the audio above a certain frequency, like above 17,000 Hz. So, can anybody help me out to achieve this? It really would help my career a lot.

Comment: To _record_ only above that frequency or to run through a filter to _select_ only above that frequency?

Comment: Well, you'd have to run the digitized sound through some sort of digital filter to filter out the lower frequencies.  But note that 17KHz is a pretty high frequency.  The highest common audio sampling rate (and the probable limit on iPhone) is 44100, meaning that the top frequency it can handle is 22.05KHz.

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to use the accelerate framework, inside there is a vDSP API that could do FFT(Fast Fourier Transform). It will convert the data from time domain to frequency domain. According the bin size information, you could extract the magnitude/amplitude after the certain bin size.

I think this could solve your problem.

For vDSP, you could refer to [aurioTouch 2](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/aurioTouch2/Listings/Classes_aurioTouchAppDelegate_mm.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40011369-Classes_aurioTouchAppDelegate_mm-DontLinkElementID_6) from Apple website.

For how FFT work in there, you could refer to this question - [Understanding FFT in aurioTouch2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8845542/1388536)

I hope this help.

**P.S.** AurioTouch or AurioTouch 1 is not using the vDSP API. I remember before iOS 4 there is an FFT function that could do similar thing but slower. So you may think that vDSP is only available after iOS4.0

Comment: Did you look at the **aurio Touch 2** samples above?

Answer (score 1):

I researched in internet  I found these two inks..

A lib to find the frequency https://github.com/jkells/sc_listener

A example using the above library https://github.com/jkells/sc_listener_sample

I hope by getting the frequency numbers and  putting a condition you can achieve this..  Hope this helps...

Answer (score 0):

Using a FFT is computationally expensive and overly complex when compared to simple filter solutions. Unless you really need to do work in the frequency domain, you should avoid it.

Instead, run your PCM through a high-pass filter. The relevant wikipedia page will help you select an appropriate filter. If your minimum frequency limit is a constant, [this page](http://www-users.cs.york.ac.uk/~fisher/mkfilter/trad.html) will generate the constants for your filter. Otherwise, it's not too difficult to dynamically generate those constants. Or you could use [the source code](http://www-users.cs.york.ac.uk/~fisher/software/mkfilter/) for said filter-coefficient generation page